# Firefox mobile resizes screen when scrolling to bottom from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox

there is a very interesting situation I am facing right now that I would like to ask about, I have a web site which is called from any device (Tablet, smarthphone, Laptop, etc.) and I have a problem only with Firefox on the smarthphones, here is the scenario:

There is a page that has a text box at the end, when the text box is focused the keyboard comes out (I mean in the smarthphones) and takes part of the screen, for the user to see the textbox and what is he writing I execute a javascript function in the **onfocus** event of the textbox that scrolls to the end of the page, I have tried with two different aproaches having the same result:

```
function scrollToMe(tBox) {
var element = document.getElementById(tBox);
setTimeout(function () { element.scrollIntoView(true); }, 600);
return false;}
```

Here tBox is the textbox, I just scroll down to him after 600 miliseconds.

```
function scrollInPage() {
var element = document.getElementById('theDIV');
setTimeout(function () { element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight; }, 600);
return false;}
```

Here I apply scroll to the general div.

Both functions work perfect in all mobile browsers I have tested except in Firefox, the div mentioned above has nothing special, just has the **overflow:scroll;** property in the css, here is how it looks the page after the scroll down function in all other mobile browsers I have tested:

[image]

The page moves to the end, this works in Chrome, Opera Mini, Safari, Dolphin, Default Android Browser, Web Browser, Chrome Dev and Ghostery.

But this is what Mozilla does after the scroll function is executed:

[image]

It just resizes the div, **only Firefox in the Smarthphones** does it and after more than 8 hours trying to solve it and searching in Internet any clue on how to do it I would like to ask if someone has an idea of what could be the issue.
 I am testing with a galaxy Note 4, a Galaxy S4 and Galaxy S3 Mini (Firefox 48 for all of them), it does the same in all of them.

Many thanks in advance for any answer and comment.

Comment: There is probably more at play than just that JavaScript. Try making a [mcve].

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara Thanks for your comment, that javascript function is all that there is, nothing happens on server side and no other client side functions are executed, the only "special" css is that of overflow:scroll that I mentioned, the other css properties are border-color, font-size, width, height, etc. and what is super interesting is that only Firefox does it, about my question I will edit it to make it more clear. thanks again.

Comment: The HTML, CSS, meta tags etcetera can still be a factor, even if it is not obvious.